# Getting Invalid Operation Exception sometimes in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, invalidoperationexception

On production, I am investigating following Exception in Log Files.
This exception comes on some of the records while fetching them from XML Service.

I have investigated all possible causes that are documented on
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 Error message: The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
    Stack trace    at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32 ordinal)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

Following is the code where i get this exception

```
  public bool Insert(PTransaction transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new DsModel())
                {
                    var query = from row in context.PTransactions
                        where
                            row.Id == transaction.Id
                            && row.Title == transaction.Title
                            && row.Author == transaction.Author
                            && row.BookType == transaction.BookType
                            && row.Imprint == transaction.Imprint
                            && row.PublicationDate == transaction.PublicationDate
                            && row.CreatedDateUTC == transaction.CreatedDateUTC.Date
                            //&& row.LastUpdatedDate == transaction.LastUpdatedDate.Date
                            && row.SupplierPriceBeforeDiscount == transaction.SupplierPriceBeforeDiscount
                            && row.SupplierPriceAfterDiscount == transaction.SupplierPriceAfterDiscount
                            && row.RetailerPriceBeforeDiscount == transaction.RetailerPriceBeforeDiscount
                            && row.RetailerPriceAfterDiscount == transaction.RetailerPriceAfterDiscount
                           // && row.RecommendedRetailPrice == transaction.RecommendedRetailPrice
                            && row.TransactionFee == transaction.TransactionFee
                            && row.CustomerId == transaction.CustomerId
                            && row.CustomerName == transaction.CustomerName
                            && row.IsLoan == transaction.IsLoan
                            && row.TransactionDateUtc == transaction.TransactionDateUtc
                        select row;

                    if (!query.Any()) //Guard if somehow it has run twice
                    {
                        transaction.kd_oprettet = DateUtil.Now();
                        context.PTransactions.Add(transaction);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Logger.Instance.Info("Transaction already exist with Identifier: " + transaction.Identifier);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.Instance.Error(string.Format(
                    "'{0}'.\nError message: {1}\nStack trace {2}",
                    transaction.Identifier, exception.Message, exception.StackTrace),exception);

                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Exception does not on occur on test environment and xml also looks fine so it looks like some code linq problem.

Please Help

This is PTransaction Class

```
    public partial class PTransaction
    {
        public int kd_id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime kd_oprettet { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string BookType { get; set; }
        public string Imprint { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> PublicationDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedDateUTC { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public decimal SupplierPriceBeforeDiscount { get; set; }
        public decimal SupplierPriceAfterDiscount { get; set; }
        public decimal RetailerPriceBeforeDiscount { get; set; }
        public decimal RetailerPriceAfterDiscount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> RecommendedRetailPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionFee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsLoan { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LegalEntityId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TransactionDateUtc { get; set; }

        public virtual PLegalEntity PLegalEntity { get; set; }
    }
```

Please have a look at PLegalEntity class

```
  public partial class PLegalEntity
    {
        public PLegalEntity()
        {
            this.PTransactions = new HashSet<PTransaction>();
        }

        public int kd_id { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PTransaction> Pransactions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills IsLoan is nullable property

Comment: @mjwills I have atttached code in Question at the end

Comment: @mjwills PLegalEntity Information is not coming from Xml, it's hardcoded

Comment: Comment all of the `bool` and nullable `bool` properties out of your source code. Add them back in one by one. When the exception starts, that is the property causing the issue.

Comment: @mjwills Exception doesn't come on Local Environment, It comes on production, i can't change the code there unless issue is identified. DB is same

Comment: Please change your code to log the contents of the XML when the exception occurs. Then include the problematic XML in your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157790/discussion-between-charlie-and-mjwills).

Comment: @Evk "while fetching them from XML Service."

Comment: Is the IsActive bool in PLegalaEntity nullable in the DB?

Comment: Any luck getting a copy of the problematic XML @Charlie ?